# Establishing WebSocket connection on localhost

Tags: php, html, websocket

I have source code for a WebSocket chat system, downloaded from [here](http://www.abrandao.com/2013/06/websockets-html5-php/).

I'm trying to open this in localhost using XAMPP.

Here is the Chrome URL:

http://localhost/code/projects/chat/03/index.php

In `index.php`, I replaced this line:

```
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/demo/server.php";
```

With this:

```
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/code/projects/chat/03/server.php";
```

In `server.php`, I replaced this line:

```
"WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n"
```

With this:

```
"WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:9000/code/projects/chat/03/shout.php\r\n"
```

On the console, I'm getting this error:

> (index):64 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/code/projects/chat/03/server.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Can anyone help?

BTW, I don't see any `shout.php` in the downloaded files.

Comment: I see `9000` and then `900`

Comment: @TheRealChx101, thanks, I replaced but the problem remains, with the same error.  I updated the post.

Comment: You do understand what `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means, don't you? Do you even have a WebSocket server running on `localhost:9000` to begin with? You can't connect to something that isn't running.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, running apache (on xampp) is not enough? How to run that on localhost?

Comment: @puerto are you sure it is listening on port 9000? Use a tool like netstat to verify. A "Connection Refused" error means either 1) you tried to connect to an IP:Port that is not listening for connections; 2) the IP:Port has too many pending connections; 3) the IP:Port is being blocked, such as by a firewall.